# Select data with OR Case and still getting me wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting data from `MySQL` table with a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT n.email, e.Name, e.Surname, e.Telephone, e.Street
FROM `nonvalid` n
LEFT JOIN `enq` e ON n.`enqID` = e.ID 
WHERE (LENGTH(e.Telephone) > 0 OR LENGTH(e.Street) > 0) GROUP BY n.email";
```

But i still see [image]

Lines 1 and 2 are fine but 3 and 4 which has nothing in both fields still is showing. Any ideas?

Comment: query seems ok.......... check the same query without Group by, then check it with Simple Join....

Comment: without GROUP BY gives me duplicate results as well

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.email, e.Name, e.Surname, e.Telephone, e.Street
FROM `nonvalid` n
LEFT JOIN `enq` e 
ON n.`enqID` = e.ID 
AND (LENGTH(e.Telephone) > 0 OR LENGTH(e.Street) > 0)
GROUP BY n.email
```

Comment: what is the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: When doing a left join, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: still having the same false data which i should not be getting

Comment: plz elaborate your question ?

Comment: no i am not saying it. i said explain your question with example(dummy data) then i can help you.

Comment: as you can see the data i have with black color in the picture exist and others are null. sorry but i cannot provide existing data

Comment: you can use dummy data i cant say you put your original data. and also give the expected output. this can help to all

Answer (score 1):

this because your left join, you make a left join, so all records in the left table will be displayed and in this case the right table columns (e.Telephone, e.Street) will be null

Comment: can you send snapshot of results

Comment: @BRG you make a left join, so all records in the left table will be displayed and in this case the right table columns (street, tel) will be null

Comment: so what should i do then not to return null values? maybe a right join?

Comment: @BRG use inner join, replace this **LEFT JOIN** with **INNER JOIN**

Comment: i have the same result with Inner join as well

Comment: @BRG did you put this in join (LENGTH(e.Telephone) > 0 OR LENGTH(e.Street) > 0)

Comment: can you send me schema of your tables?